# Retrieving doc().id from google firebase documents from individual components in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a screen that lists "tasks" all being the same component `<TaskItem>` just with different props sent to them.

Each `<TaskItem>` is created by iterating over documents in a Firestore database collection.

I want to access the doc().id of the individual  when they are clicked.

My question is: How can I access the doc().id for each particular `<TaskItem>` after they are rendered? Is this doc().id somehow attached or stored with the `<TaskItem>` when it is created?

`tasks1` retreives the tasks from the backend and creates an array to use `map` on

```
db.collection('users').doc(id).collection('tasks').onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
          const tempTasks = [];
          snapshot.forEach(
             doc => {
                 tempTasks.push(doc.data());
             }
          )
          setTasks(tempTasks);
      });
```

Firestore Database structure

```
db.collection('users').doc(id).collection('tasks').doc().id
```

I Iterate, using `map` over 'tasks' and create a `<TaskItem>` for each 'tasks' item in the database. Is the doc().id for each stored with it or do I somehow have to manually access it?

```
<View style={styles.tasks}>
                    
                        {tasks1.map((task) => {
                            return (

                                <View style={{ margin: 4}}>
                                <TaskItem
                                    //PROPS
                                    notes={task.notes}
                                    reminder={task.reminder}
                                    name={task.name}
                                    assigned={task.assigned}
                                    tagName = {task.tag}
                                    profileImage={task.profileImage}
                                    color={task.color}
                                    changeModal={() => changeStateHandler()}
                                    onPress={()=>setTagClicked(!tagClicked)}
                                />
                                </View>
                            );
                        })}
                    </View>
```

[image: I want to retrieve the ID underlined in red for each individual task as its selected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using `.data()`, your object only contains the fields which you have stored in Firestore. You can have both data and the document ID by adding a few lines, like this:

```
doc => {
  var newData = doc.data();
  newData.id = doc.id;
  tempTasks.push(newData);
}
```

Comment: ok great thanks! I was wondering If I would have to do something like this or if React knew that upon selecting the task which document it was....seems I need to manually store it as you have mentioned.

Comment: Technically, after using `.data()`, it's referring to a different object now. Because `.data()` is a method on `documentSnapshot`. `id` is a parameter specific to the documentSnapshot, like the boolean `exists`..etc. If it answered your question, kindly consider marking it as the solution to your question.

Comment: this seems to have answered the question...so my goal is to click on one of the tasks in a list, a modal will pop up with a delete button and then I can delete it. That is why i need to access the doc().id...if I select a task now I should be able to access it?

Comment: It is stored inside your `newData` object, before pushing it to `tempTasks`. Try it.